# jQuery: Count number of clicks for hundreds of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first question here at SO. Basically I have a huge number of elements on page and I want to count and display the number of times a user clicks each of them. But for that I would need to define variables for each element.
Isn't there an easier way?

For one element:

```
 var counter = 0;
 $('.container').on("click", function(){
 counter = counter+1;
 $(this).find('.tag').html(counter);
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a class to group these elements?

Comment: @wei2912 Please elaborate.

Comment: Simplest is to put a numeric property directly on the element to hold its count. Just make sure the name avoids conflicts, like: `this.__counter__ = this.__counter__ + 1 || 1;`

Comment: @Shikharsportal It appears that you want individual counts for each element, so my comment is no longer relevant.

Comment: @wei2912 Yeah! Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) with each element counting the number of times each was clicked.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.container').click(function(){
        if ($(this).data('count')) { // already been clicked
            $(this).data('count', $(this).data('count') + 1); // add one
        } else { // first click
            $(this).data('count', 1); // initialize the count
        }
        $(this).html($(this).data('count')); // show it
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
<div class="container">container</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. But I can't seem to make it work. Can you help by creating a fiddle?

Comment: I added a Stack Snippet that you can run right from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a class for all the elements you want to count.

```
 var counter = 0;
 $('.someClass').on("click", function(){
  counter++;
  $(this).find('.tag').html(counter);
 });
```

Comment: Each element has a different precomputed class.