# Case of the second element is not executed when the value is 5

Tags: jquery

I wrote a script that, depending on the number of clicks, animates individual field values to specific values. The script works ok, only one problem appears. When the first field is MAX (case 5), nothing happens in the next field after clicking on the plus.

I can not figure out why a piece of script is wrong. Can you help?

```js
click = 0;
 
$(".max").on("click", function() {
  
 elem = $(this).prev();
  
 switch(click) {
  case 0:
  elem.animateNumber({number: 25000});
  break;
  case 1:
  elem.animateNumber({number: 50000});
  break;
  case 2:
  elem.animateNumber({number: 75000});
  break;
  case 3:
  elem.animateNumber({number: 100000});
  break;
  case 4:
  elem.animateNumber({number: 500000});
  break;
  case 5:
  elem.text("MAX");
  break;
 }

 click++;
  
});
 
$(".min").on("click", function() {
 
 elem = $(this).next();
  
 switch(click) {
 case 0:
 elem.text("MIN");
 break;
 case 1:
 elem.animateNumber({number: 10000});
 break;
 case 2:
 elem.animateNumber({number: 25000});
 break;
 case 3:
 elem.animateNumber({number: 50000});
 break;
 case 4:
 elem.animateNumber({number: 75000});
 break;
 case 5:
 elem.animateNumber({number: 100000});
 break;
 }

 click--;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-animateNumber/0.0.14/jquery.animateNumber.js"></script>
<section class="gen-box-field">
   <button type="button" class="min">-</button>
   <div id="param1">10000</div>
   <button type="button" class="max">+</button>
</section>
<section class="gen-box-field">
   <button type="button" class="min">-</button>
   <div id="param2">10000</div>
   <button type="button" class="max">+</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Here's your issue: click is shared. the variable click is not contained within either element, but it's shared between them. Instead, you may want to consider creating an array like this: `var clicked = [0,0], and then access the member of the array whose index matches the index of .gen-box-field

Comment: Can you show me any example?

Comment: Snowmonkey is right about your problem. I'd actually use [.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a separate click count for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've created an array called click, and then I used the index of the .gen-box-field container as the position in the array for the value I want. I've tried to comment enough to make it all make sense, feel free to ask if any of this is confusing.

Another change I made is, rather than having the callback hard-coded in both the min and max button's event handlers, I created a single function that both use for their callback. The functionality is exactly the same in both cases, the only difference being incrementing or decrementing. Doing this saves coding time, and if ever you have to debug, you're only debugging in a single location.

Best of luck!

```js
// as I've got multiple gen-box-field, I need an array for
//  to store the click values. Or, as another poster mentioned,
//  I could also store the data-click attribute directly on the
//  param field, for example.
var click = [-1, -1];

// As both .max and .min do the exact same thing, we can really
//  use the same callback function for both.
function handleClick(event) {

  // for my own convenience, I create a reference to the clicked
  //   button.
  var clickedEl = $(this);
  // This tells me which of the gen-box-field containers holds the
  //   button that was clicked. I'll use that to index the click
  //   array. we use index('.gen-box-field") as we don't want ALL
  //   sibling nodes of the .gen-box-field, simply that collection.
  var which = clickedEl.parents(".gen-box-field").index(".gen-box-field");
  // reference to the element we'll be animating.
  var elem = clickedEl.parents(".gen-box-field").find(".param");

  // The math to count clicks should happen BEFORE the animation.
  //  Otherwise, clicking the + and then the - results in weird
  //  behaviors. Using the class of the clicked el, we can see
  //  if it is the + or the - that has been clicked, and do math!
  if (clickedEl.hasClass("max") && click[which] < 5) {
    // It was the plus button. Increment!
    click[which]++;
  } else if (clickedEl.hasClass("min") && click[which] >= 0) {
    // It was the minus button. down, down to goblin town...
    click[which]--
  }

  // And having incremented or decremented, do the animation.
  switch (click[which]) {
    case -1:
      elem.text("MIN");
      break;
    case 0:
      elem.animateNumber({
        number: 25000
      });
      break;
    case 1:
      elem.animateNumber({
        number: 50000
      });
      break;
    case 2:
      elem.animateNumber({
        number: 75000
      });
      break;
    case 3:
      elem.animateNumber({
        number: 100000
      });
      break;
    case 4:
      elem.animateNumber({
        number: 500000
      });
      break;
    case 5:
      elem.text("MAX");
      break;
  }
};

// BOTH buttons get the same callback function. Thus, no code 
//   is being duplicated, any fixes I need to make all happen in
//   one place. Easy-peasy!
$(".max").on("click", handleClick);

$(".min").on("click", handleClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-animateNumber/0.0.14/jquery.animateNumber.js"></script>
<section class="gen-box-field">
  <button type="button" class="min">-</button>
  <div class="param" id="param1">10000</div>
  <button type="button" class="max">+</button>
</section>
<section class="gen-box-field">
  <button type="button" class="min">-</button>
  <div class="param" id="param2">10000</div>
  <button type="button" class="max">+</button>
</section>
```

To answer your question about why clicking the + and then the - resulted in the value incrementing instead of decrementing, the increment/decrement math was happening AFTER the animation. Brain disengaged or something. So it was acting on the LAST click result, not the CURRENT click result. Instead, I've moved the math before the animation, and all works as expected.

Comment: Nice! I have found such a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959525/jquery-count-number-of-clicks-for-hundreds-of-elements but your way its its better. Thank you so much

Comment: One thing I did have to change, where you use $(this).prev() or $(this).next() to get to the param field, I can't, as I don't know which directon I want (I don't really know the position of the clicked el). Instead, I refer to the containing el, and find the .param el within that. Hope this worked out, and glad to help. ;)

Comment: With your script is a little problem. Namely - when clicking max, and next click min value is added first, that is, takes the next case, and only then returns to the previous one. How can this be mitigated?

Comment: My bad, @sauero. that was mitigated by moving the increment/decrement math to occur before the animation effect. All fixed above.